# Restore or reset Oracle database (No Flashback features)

Tags: java, oracle, rman

I am running

```
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
```

Seem it not Enterprise edition, so I not able to use flashback features

```
SQL> ALTER DATABASE FLASHBACK ON;
ALTER DATABASE FLASHBACK ON
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Flashback Database

SQL> SELECT flashback_on, log_mode FROM v$database;
FLASHBACK_ON |LOG_MODE     
-------------|-------------
NO           |NOARCHIVELOG
```

As you see my database are running with NOARCHIVELOG mode and my filesystem is ext3

I had to do CRUD test with my system + another vendor. and after that I want to revert back  to the state of "restore point" (before testing). In short word, I don't want to keep test data inside my database.

There is discussion [here, but this is using flashback features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613655/fastest-way-to-reset-oracle-database-for-testing). But how about for my case?

Is there any solution suitable for me?

Comment: Export / import?

Comment: Use RMAN to take a backup of the tables/schema/database and then restore it after the test has completed. It will not be fast but you will put it back to the previous state. Alternatively, use a mocking framework and mock the database calls.

Comment: Another suggestion: use a database on a virtual machine for your testing then overwrite it with a blank image when you're finished. Docker is popular these days; also Oracle maintains images for its own Virtual Box, although you might struggle to find official images for old versions (which 11gR2 is, at least in Oracle's eyes).

Comment: @MT0 if i doing integration test with other system (another vendor). Mocking are used for my internal. We cannot expect what data will be throw-into our system. But after test done. I want to clean-up as before testing. Honestly, i not good with rman, please let me know the details. :)

Comment: @APC well, my OS is mounted on exsi but database disk is not virtual.

Comment: What sort of testing do you have in mine? My initial assumption was that you were looking to stand up a test database for some form of regular testing such as regression testing. Your subsequent comments seem to discount that. Indeed it sounds scarily like this could be your Production database you're running in `norarchivelog` mode. You should **edit your question** to provide more details about your scenario if you still want our help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without archivelog mode and depending on size of database and downtime you have only two options either volume snapshot or rman cold backup.

`Below is steps by using rman cold backup.`

```
C:\sql>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Jan 24 22:31:10 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
SQL> select log_mode,flashback_on from v$database;

LOG_MODE     FLASHBACK_ON
------------ ------------------
NOARCHIVELOG NO

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

C:\sql> rman target /

Recovery Manager: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Jan 24 22:10:48 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

connected to target database: ORA (DBID=1582999497, not open)


RMAN> shutdown immediate;

using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
database closed
database dismounted
Oracle instance shut down

RMAN> startup mount

connected to target database (not started)
Oracle instance started
database mounted

Total System Global Area    1068937216 bytes

Fixed Size                     2182592 bytes
Variable Size                583008832 bytes
Database Buffers             469762048 bytes
Redo Buffers                  13983744 bytes

RMAN> backup format 'G:\ora\%I_%t.bkup'  database;

Starting backup at 24-JAN-19
using channel ORA_DISK_1
using channel ORA_DISK_2
using channel ORA_DISK_3
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting full datafile backup set
channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
input datafile file number=00006 name=C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\BSTUFF01.DBF
input datafile file number=00002 name=C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\SYSAUX01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting piece 1 at 24-JAN-19
channel ORA_DISK_2: starting full datafile backup set
channel ORA_DISK_2: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
input datafile file number=00007 name=C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\SOE.DBF
input datafile file number=00003 name=C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\UNDOTBS01.DBF
input datafile file number=00001 name=C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\SYSTEM01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_2: starting piece 1 at 24-JAN-19
channel ORA_DISK_3: starting full datafile backup set
channel ORA_DISK_3: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
input datafile file number=00004 name=C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\USERS01.DBF
input datafile file number=00005 name=C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\EXAMPLE01.DBF
input datafile file number=00008 name=C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\GGATE01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_3: starting piece 1 at 24-JAN-19
channel ORA_DISK_2: finished piece 1 at 24-JAN-19
piece handle=G:\ORA\1582999497_998431563.BKUP tag=TAG20190124T220602 comment=NONE
channel ORA_DISK_2: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:05:36
channel ORA_DISK_1: finished piece 1 at 24-JAN-19
piece handle=G:\ORA\1582999497_998431562.BKUP tag=TAG20190124T220602 comment=NONE
channel ORA_DISK_1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:05:37
channel ORA_DISK_3: finished piece 1 at 24-JAN-19
piece handle=G:\ORA\1582999497_998431564.BKUP tag=TAG20190124T220602 comment=NONE
channel ORA_DISK_3: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:05:36
Finished backup at 24-JAN-19

Starting Control File and SPFILE Autobackup at 24-JAN-19
piece handle=C:\ORA\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DB_1\DATABASE\CF_C-1582999497-20190124-05 comment=NONE
Finished Control File and SPFILE Autobackup at 24-JAN-19

RMAN> list backup summary;



List of Backups
===============
Key     TY LV S Device Type Completion Time #Pieces #Copies Compressed Tag
------- -- -- - ----------- --------------- ------- ------- ---------- ---
120     B  F  A DISK        24-JAN-19       1       1       NO         TAG20190124T220602
121     B  F  A DISK        24-JAN-19       1       1       NO         TAG20190124T220602
122     B  F  A DISK        24-JAN-19       1       1       NO         TAG20190124T220602
123     B  F  A DISK        24-JAN-19       1       1       NO         TAG20190124T221140


C:\sql>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Jan 24 22:31:10 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


SQL> create restore point pre_testing;  -- create restore point before testing

Restore point created.

SQL> col name format A15

SQL> col scn format 999999999

SQL> select name,scn from v$restore_point;    

NAME                   SCN
--------------- ----------
PRE_TESTING       26708339

SQL> conn tom/tom
Connected.

SQL> select * from cat;

TABLE_NAME                     TABLE_TYPE
------------------------------ -----------
T                              TABLE

 ---create a new table and drop exiting table    

SQL> create table t2 as select * from t where 1 < 1;

Table created.

SQL> select * from cat;

TABLE_NAME                     TABLE_TYPE
------------------------------ -----------
T                              TABLE
T2                             TABLE

SQL> drop table t purge;

Table dropped.

SQL> select * from cat;

TABLE_NAME                     TABLE_TYPE
------------------------------ -----------
T2                             TABLE

SQL> conn scott/tiger
Connected.


SQL> select * from emp;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE                   SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 1980-12-17 00:00:00        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 1981-02-20 00:00:00       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 1981-02-22 00:00:00       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 1981-04-02 00:00:00       2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 1981-09-28 00:00:00       1250       1400         30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 1981-05-01 00:00:00       2850                    30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 1981-06-09 00:00:00       2450                    10
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 1987-04-19 00:00:00       3000                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            1981-11-17 00:00:00       5000                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 1981-09-08 00:00:00       1500          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 1987-05-23 00:00:00       1100                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 1981-12-03 00:00:00        950                    30
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 1981-12-03 00:00:00       3000                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 1982-01-23 00:00:00       1300                    10

14 rows selected.

SQL> insert into emp values(9999,'Mick','SUPERMAN',7839,sysdate,9999,1,10);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from emp;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE                   SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      9999 Mick       SUPERMAN        7839 2019-01-24 22:20:17       9999          1         10   -- new record inserted
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 1980-12-17 00:00:00        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 1981-02-20 00:00:00       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 1981-02-22 00:00:00       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 1981-04-02 00:00:00       2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 1981-09-28 00:00:00       1250       1400         30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 1981-05-01 00:00:00       2850                    30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 1981-06-09 00:00:00       2450                    10
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 1987-04-19 00:00:00       3000                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            1981-11-17 00:00:00       5000                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 1981-09-08 00:00:00       1500          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 1987-05-23 00:00:00       1100                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 1981-12-03 00:00:00        950                    30
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 1981-12-03 00:00:00       3000                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 1982-01-23 00:00:00       1300                    10

15 rows selected.




SQL> select count(*) from emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        15

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options


-- now we revert back to original state

C:\sql>rman target /

Recovery Manager: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Jan 24 22:21:17 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

connected to target database: ORA (DBID=1582999497)

RMAN> shutdown immediate;

using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
database closed
database dismounted
Oracle instance shut down

RMAN> startup mount

connected to target database (not started)
Oracle instance started
database mounted

Total System Global Area    1068937216 bytes

Fixed Size                     2182592 bytes
Variable Size                583008832 bytes
Database Buffers             469762048 bytes
Redo Buffers                  13983744 bytes

RMAN> restore database until restore point pre_testing;


Starting restore at 24-JAN-19
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=96 device type=DISK
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_2
channel ORA_DISK_2: SID=189 device type=DISK
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_3
channel ORA_DISK_3: SID=221 device type=DISK

channel ORA_DISK_1: starting datafile backup set restore
channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying datafile(s) to restore from backup set
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00001 to C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\SYSTEM01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00003 to C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\UNDOTBS01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: restoring datafile 00007 to C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\SOE.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_1: reading from backup piece G:\ORA\1582999497_998431563.BKUP
channel ORA_DISK_2: starting datafile backup set restore
channel ORA_DISK_2: specifying datafile(s) to restore from backup set
channel ORA_DISK_2: restoring datafile 00002 to C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\SYSAUX01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_2: restoring datafile 00006 to C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\BSTUFF01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_2: reading from backup piece G:\ORA\1582999497_998431562.BKUP
channel ORA_DISK_3: starting datafile backup set restore
channel ORA_DISK_3: specifying datafile(s) to restore from backup set
channel ORA_DISK_3: restoring datafile 00004 to C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\USERS01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_3: restoring datafile 00005 to C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\EXAMPLE01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_3: restoring datafile 00008 to C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\GGATE01.DBF
channel ORA_DISK_3: reading from backup piece G:\ORA\1582999497_998431564.BKUP
channel ORA_DISK_2: piece handle=G:\ORA\1582999497_998431562.BKUP tag=TAG20190124T220602
channel ORA_DISK_2: restored backup piece 1
channel ORA_DISK_2: restore complete, elapsed time: 00:03:06
channel ORA_DISK_1: piece handle=G:\ORA\1582999497_998431563.BKUP tag=TAG20190124T220602
channel ORA_DISK_1: restored backup piece 1
channel ORA_DISK_1: restore complete, elapsed time: 00:03:16
channel ORA_DISK_3: piece handle=G:\ORA\1582999497_998431564.BKUP tag=TAG20190124T220602
channel ORA_DISK_3: restored backup piece 1
channel ORA_DISK_3: restore complete, elapsed time: 00:03:16
Finished restore at 24-JAN-19

RMAN> recover database until restore point pre_testing;


Starting recover at 24-JAN-19
using channel ORA_DISK_1
using channel ORA_DISK_2
using channel ORA_DISK_3

starting media recovery

archived log for thread 1 with sequence 2 is already on disk as file C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\REDO02.LOG
archived log file name=C:\ORA\ORADATA\ORA\REDO02.LOG thread=1 sequence=2
media recovery complete, elapsed time: 00:00:04
Finished recover at 24-JAN-19

RMAN> alter database open resetlogs;

database opened

RMAN> exit


Recovery Manager complete.

C:\sql>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Jan 24 22:27:43 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select count(*) from emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL> select * from emp;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE                   SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 1980-12-17 00:00:00        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 1981-02-20 00:00:00       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 1981-02-22 00:00:00       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 1981-04-02 00:00:00       2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 1981-09-28 00:00:00       1250       1400         30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 1981-05-01 00:00:00       2850                    30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 1981-06-09 00:00:00       2450                    10
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 1987-04-19 00:00:00       3000                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            1981-11-17 00:00:00       5000                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 1981-09-08 00:00:00       1500          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 1987-05-23 00:00:00       1100                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 1981-12-03 00:00:00        950                    30
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 1981-12-03 00:00:00       3000                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 1982-01-23 00:00:00       1300                    10

14 rows selected.

SQL> conn tom/tom

SQL> select * from cat;

TABLE_NAME                     TABLE_TYPE
------------------------------ -----------
T                              TABLE


SQL> drop restore point pre_testing;

Restore point dropped.
```

**Edit:You can skip creating restore point and just restore and recover database with rman**

Answer (score 0):

If takeing a rman backup, remember that is has to be an offline backup. Expdp/impdp is an option only if your data is not too big.
You could do filesystem/VM snapshoting depending on your environment.

If your data is of any value to you, please activate the archivelog mode and take consistent backups of your database. The database does it‘s best to safeguard your data please don‘t sabotage the.effort by not takeing backups.

Comment: Maybe you @jmk mean about ZFS file system, but no. Because we are using ext3. Datapump also not suitable because of large data. archivelog  maybe the solution, but i try to find solution without change the LOG_MODE first

Comment: The Prime Directive of all DBAs is "You will not lose data".  If you fail in this, nothing else you do as a DBA will matter.  The only way of meeting this directive with oracle databases is 1) run your database in archivelog mode, 2) take regular _rman_ backups, and 3) practice recovering from backup. Your desire to not run in archivelog, and your seeming desire to not learn rman, is truly frightening.  Rman (even without being in archivelog mode) would make your immediate task (restore to pre-test condition) drop-dead simple.

Comment: @RobbiNespu Snapshoting can be done on Linux eg with lvm snapshots if your filesystem does not support it. It boils down to: Know what you are doing. My recommendation: take an offline rman backup and really think about using archive logs. What is your concern with them? You can't back up your database online right now so every backup you try to make will result in a downtime. We don't want to do some secret snapshot and do a dirty recovery if something goes wrong, do we ;-)